# Applying Style to DataGridCell programmatically with Converter

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to apply this XAML style to DataGrid's Cell via code:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Item.Dif, Converter={StaticResource RedValues}}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

So far on my code I can apply a Setter on the TextAlignmentProperty but not on the foreground:

```
Style style2 = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
style2.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right));
style2.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, new RedValues()));

codb = new DataGridTextColumn();
codb.Binding = new Binding("Dif") {
    StringFormat = "C",
    ConverterCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-PT") };
codb.Header = "Dif";
codb.CellStyle = style2;
grid.Columns.Add(codb);
```

And this is my Converter Class:

```
class RedValues: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is decimal) {
                decimal quantity = (decimal)value;
                if (quantity < 0)
                    return Brushes.IndianRed;
                if (quantity > 0)
                    return Brushes.ForestGreen;
                return Brushes.Black; 
            }

            return Brushes.Yellow;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you haven't applied any converter in code ? whats your question exactly ?

Comment: Is how to apply the converter

Comment: I guess ans should help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this if you want to assign a binding with converter from code ..

```
style2.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, new Binding("Item.Dif"){Converter = new RedValues()} ))};
```

for your case -- you may add all your relative code and path bindings as you feel like ..

Comment: Thanks a lot. I needed to create a DataGrid programmatically in order to print some data, and having negatives values in red is a must :)